# Identical formula fields with different results

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that tracks the sales of inventory items per month over a 12 month period, then shows the average sold per month.  I have 2 identical formula fields, each with unique names, but identical code.  The first formula field returns zero for every inventory item, while the second formula returns the correctly calculated average over a 12 month period.  Both formula fields are placed within the same section of the report.

Here is the code for both formula fields.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared NumberVar num;
Shared NumberVar total;
Shared NumberVar result;
If num = 0 Then result := 0 else result := total / num;
result;
```

My report is currently working, since the second formula field functions as expected.  At this point I would like to understand why the first formula field does not work.

I tried removing the logic that detects zero in the denominator.  The formula that works current continues to work without issue when this logic is removed.  The broken formula throws the "Divide by Zero" error.  I'm also surprised that the working formula continues to work with this logic removed because I have rows in my dataset that have NULL values for some periods.  This is due to a constraint upon the report for new inventory items added during a period after the 1st period being reported.  For example, if the report covers 2018 for periods 1 through 12 (Jan through Dec), and a new item is added to inventory during period 5, it should return a NULL value for periods 1 through 4, and a numeric value for periods 5 through 8.  The average across the 12 periods should not include periods with a NULL value.  To accomplish this I use a variable to count the periods during which the item contained numeric data and use this counter as the denominator when calculating the average.

I have created additional formula fields to output the values of each individual variable and placed them in the report.  All of the variables have the values that I would expect them to hold at each iteration of the section containing them.

Can anyone help me understand why these two identical formula fields each output different results?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Shared NumberVar result
```

to

```
Local NumberVar result
```

With Shared, the value change in one formula impacts the value change in the other.

Comment: A Local scope won't work unfortunately.  The value of the variable is populated from a subreport, then recalled in the main report.  I'm aware how two formula fields using the same variable will impact each other.  My problem was the original formula field I created did not work as expected, then when I created the exact same formula field again, it worked.

Comment: And currently, the report functions as intended, I just want to understand why two identical formula fields are giving different results despite having the same formula and properties.